# I have upgraded to GA4, but I am not getting realtime reports like in Universal Analytics. Is it achievable? Please take a look at the pictures below

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

this is GA4 result

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByEJg.png)]

this is Universal analytics result at the same time

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0N9V.png)]

how can I view GA4 result same or closer to universal analytics, is it achievable?

I have little knowledge of programming, though I tried changing tracking code to show data from last 5 minutes (as per UA) but it didn't worked.